# .NET Core 5 GET Action Called Twice

Tags: session, request, asp.net-core-mvc

**Environment**

- .NET Core 5 Web Application
- IIS 10
- Azure VM

**Issue**

Executing a GET action results in that action being called a second time. The first call shows cookie information. The second does not show cookie information.

What we've tried:

- Occurs for GET requests but not POST requests
- Occurs without a view (NOT a javascript issue)
- Browser does not show two requests. This occurs server-side.
- Does not occur in Firefox Privacy Mode
- Does not occur on localhost. Only in production.
- Occurs with HTTPS off
- Fork of the solution does not exhibit this behavior (makes middleware unlikely cause)

Best guesses:

- .NET 5 (deprecated) or dependencies (*a bad developer blames his tools*)
- IIS Settings
- Session

Code example:

Controller

```
// no other filters
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DupeRequestTest()
{
        // database insert with Dapper
        var sql = @"INSERT INTO TrackingTable
                    (CookieJson, CreateDate)
                    VALUES(@CookieJson, GETDATE());";
        using var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        con.Open();
        con.Execute(sql, new
        {
            CookieJson=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Cookies),
        });
        
        // returning a status code so no View, javascript, or other requests
        return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Database results:

| CookieJson | CreateDate |
| --- | --- |
| [{"Key":"SessionId","Value":"ac6f292c-1ca1-5179-9123-78a04d382dea"}] | 2022-10-25 09:46:30.523 |
| [] | 2022-10-25 09:46:30.770 |

Thank you. Any help, such as next testing steps, would be appreciated - short of building a new app.

I'm sure the answer is either very stupid or very hidden.